# How to fetch all Jobs in HPC Pack 2016 using REST API?

Tags: azure, hpc

I would like to fetch all the jobs information in Microsoft HPC Cluster 2016

From Microsoft documentation i found this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/hh529654(v%3dvs.85)

I did tried the following command from Chrome/Firefox
https://head_node_name:port/WindowsHPC/Jobs

It required me to enter user/password which i did and then it kept forcing me to enter user/password again and again. (Nothing wrong with user/password itself because i used it to connect to HPC Management from HPC client tool)

The result is i couldn't do anything.

Anyone can help me solve this?

Comment: How did you deploy your HPC cluster? AFAIK the rest api is only working when your cluster is domain joined.

Answer (score 0):

If you're browsing the url https://head_node_name:port/WindowsHPC/Jobs and the browser prompted your username and password again and again, it meant your username and password were incorrect. Did you entered your Windows Domain name prefixing your username if you're a Windows Domain user on the system? It's like `domain\username`. Otherwise you won't get passed.